# Have element scroll, then fixed when 25 pixels from window top

Tags: jquery

This is my code. It works, but there's a bug where it sometimes overlaps an image. Wondering if this is how others would code it.

```js
var $window = $(window);
var social = $('.social-links');
var elTop = social.offset().top - 25;

$window.scroll(function() {
    social.toggleClass('fixed', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML/CSS of the navbar and the image please.

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't use a $ in the window variable as that's used to create a jQuery object from the selected element. try:

```
var window = $(window);
```

I'm not sure about using the statement in the toggleClass function, as I haven't used it. I would use something similar to:

```
$window.scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elTop){
        social.toggleClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

If you can use the state in the toggle class, it would save some space obviously.

After writing this I'm wondering if you even need to set the window variable, as you will need updated information when you scroll, you will have to use $(window) to get it.